# Solving constraint modulo equation

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, optimization, modular-arithmetic

Let’s say we are given following equation:
$$ax = 2^n, a,x, n \in \mathbb{Z_+}$$
where $a$ is given. And we are interested to get the maximum x and minimum n, or actually generally any $x$ and $n$, which solve the above equation.

1) I tried to formulate it as a optimization problem:

$$ \min_n \max_x (ax-2^n= 0) $$ 
but actually I do not know how to solve a opt. problem as an integer arithmetic (because of  $\mathbb{Z_+}$).

2)  My next try was to solve it as an modulo equation (i should say i am not really an expert in this field):
$$ ax \equiv 0 \  mod(2^n)$$
but also here I do not know how to go further.

So any help, link or suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Hint: consider the factors of $ax$. Clearly, this can be solved only if $a=2^k$ for some integer $k$.

Comment: @MattiP. This is exactly what i was trying right now. Sofar i know that it can be solved iff $a=2^q \ x=2^p$ where $n=q+p$. right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By unique factorization of positive integers, such $x$ and $n$ exist if and only if $a=2^q$ for some nonnegative integer $q$. Then $x=2^p$ for some nonnegative integer $p$ and $n=p+q$.

From this it is immediate that the minimum $n$ is then $n=q$, with $p=0$ and so $x=2^0=1$. It is also immediate that there is no maximum $x$.